# StreamProvider not updating state

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am trying to use a `StreamProvider` (from [this](https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider) awesome package), but I've been struggling to get a particular stream to work.

I create a `StreamController` which I use to add data to its `Stream` via its `Sink`. All of this seems to be working fine. But when using this `Stream` with a `StreamProvider`, the widget tree does not reflect the changes of the `Stream`. It does however work fine using a `StreamBuilder`.

The code using a `StreamProvider`:

```
class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Mockup exchange = ExchangeApi.mockup;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<List<Data>>(
      builder: (BuildContext context) => Wrapper.mockup.stream,
      initialData: null,
      catchError: (BuildContext context, e) {
        print("Error: $e");
        return null;
      },
      child: TestPageBody(),
    );
  }
}

class TestPageBody extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Data> dataList = Provider.of<List<Data>>(context);
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: dataList?.length ?? 0,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Text(dataList[index].name);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I have been searching why this does not work, but haven't found an answer yet. But here are some things I did find:

- Using Flutter Desktop Embedding, the UI did reflect changes from the stream when the window got resized (thus forcing to rebuild). The same effect is seen when using hot refresh.
- The stream is constantly adding new data, I tested this by debugging and simply printing out the data

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you add an `updateShouldNotify: (_, __) => true`, does this work? (this is just to confirm something)

Comment: That's it! Thanks again Rémi... But, could you clarify why this is necessary? It never seemed to be necessary with other streams I used (although this could be a coincidence). I thought the property's use case would be something like performance (limit re-rendering).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The default behavior of most providers (excluding `ChangeNotifierProvider`) is to assume that the values passed are immutable.

As such, if your stream emits the same value as previously emitted, this won't rebuild dependents.

There are two solutions:

- Make the values emitted by your stream immutable, such that performing `previousValue == newValue` works correctly.
- override `updateShouldNotify` to not filter values if they didn't change.

  A simple `updateShouldNotify: (_, __) => true` will do.

---

In the ideal world, prefer immutability.

This can be done by making a copy of your object before sending it to `streamController.add(value)`:

```dart
List<T> value;
streamController.add(List.from(value));
```

A second (optional) step is to override `updateShouldNotify` (or `operator==`  on your object) to notify the provider that the value didn't change.

With `List`, this can be done using `ListEquality` from `collection/collection.dart`:

```dart
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

StreamProvider<List<int>>(
  builder: (_) => stream,
  updateShouldNotify: const ListEquality<int>().equals,
);
```

Comment: This makes sense, as I was adding to a `List` and was not actually creating a new `List` object. Thanks for the quick reply and thanks for the great package!