# StreamProvider not updating List

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have a StreamController which should update a `List` but it doesn't happen:

```dart
class LocationService {
    StreamController<List<bg.Geofence>> geofencesController = StreamController<List<bg.Geofence>>();

    updateGeofences(geofences) {
        logger.i('listing geofences $geofences');
        geofencesController.add(List.from(list));
    }
}
```

When I call `updateGeofences` I got many geofences in logs. 
But widget are not rebuilt!

Here is my providers setup:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          StreamProvider<List<bg.Geofence>>.value(
              updateShouldNotify: (_, __) {
                logger.i('updateShouldNotify, $_, $__');
                return true;
              },
              initialData: List<bg.Geofence>(),
              stream: LocationService().geofencesController.stream)
        ],
        child: MaterialApp()
     );
  }
}
```

When I listen directly from my service with

```dart
geofencesController.stream.listen((onData) {
  logger.i('Got eem! $onData');
});
```

The streams emits new data...
But not in the StreamProvider: `updateShouldNotify` is never called (I tried without luck this [answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57365207/streamprovider-not-updating-state) solutions)

Here is how I get my data in view:

```dart
class GPSView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<bg.Geofence> geofences = Provider.of<List<bg.Geofence>>(context);
```

But this list remains empty.

I have another StreamController with a simple Map which works perfectly. What's wrong?

Comment: That may not be the problem, but you shouldn't use `.value` constructor here. See [this](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ChangeNotifierProvider-class.html)  The `Creating a ChangeNotifier` part applies to StreamProvider too

Comment: `LocationService().geofencesController.stream` creates a new `LocationService` and new `geofencesController` so you are using two different controllers

Comment: Hi @RémiRousselet! I followed https://medium.com/flutter-community/build-a-location-service-in-flutter-367a1b212f7a tutorial, which is using GetIt() to keep LocationService as a singleton. Isn't it? `locator.registerLazySingleton(() => LocationService());`

Comment: So, you got me on the track! It has nothing to do with the StreamProvider. I just need to call `locator<LocationService>()` instead of `LocationService()`. Cheers! 

Comment: Using provider with get_it is not a good idea. They are concurrents.

Comment: Hmm. What are my options? ProxyProviders? Should I follow this? https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-provider-v3-architecture-using-proxyprovider-for-injection-62cf5c58ea52 Thanks for your feedbacks!

Comment: Make a Provider for the `LocationService` instead of a locator. Then use a Consumer<LocationService> that builds a StreamProvider.value from the service.

Answer (score 1):

So thanks to @pskink & @RémiRoussele comments I managed to fix my issue:

I was recreating a `LocationService` by calling `LocationService().geofencesController.stream`.

I updated my code to

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          StreamProvider<List<bg.Geofence>>(
            builder: (_) => locator<LocationService>().geofencesController,
            initialData: List<bg.Geofence>(),
          ),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp();
  }
}
```

And everything works now! Cheers!