# How to use updateShouldNotify in StreamProvider?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I don't understand how to use updateShouldNotify in StreamProvider.

(new) StreamProvider StreamProvider({Key key}, {Stream Function(BuildContext) create}, {FirebaseUser initialData}, {FirebaseUser Function(BuildContext, Object) catchError}, {bool Function(FirebaseUser, FirebaseUser) updateShouldNotify}, {bool lazy}, {Widget child})

I didn't get much help in the doc 
https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/StreamProvider-class.html

Help plz :D

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer from Rémi Rousselet himself (the creator of the Provider package) here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57365207/streamprovider-not-updating-state

> The default behavior of most providers (excluding ChangeNotifierProvider) is to assume that the values passed are immutable. As such, if your stream emits the same value as previously emitted, this won't rebuild dependents.

The default behaviour of `updateShouldNotify` is the following, you can find an exemple here:
https://www.didierboelens.com/2019/07/provider-points-of-interest-points-to-care-about

```
updateShouldNotify: (previous, current) => (current != previous),
```

You don't need to use/override the parameter if this behaviour is good for you. However, if you want to change this default behaviour to update everytime there is a new value (no matter if it's the same or a new one), override it by using the parameter:

```
updateShouldNotify: (_, __) => true
```